# Cffile action="write" adding empty lines into my txt

Tags: coldfusion

Using ColdFusion I am updating the top line of my txt file, however once I do this it adds an empty line after each line in my txt file and I have no idea why.

A breakdown of my code is as follows:

```
<!---CSV FILE--->
<cffile action="read" file="C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/kelly2/debitorders.csv" variable="csvfile">

<cfoutput>
<!---LOOP THROUGH CSV FILE--->
<cfloop index="index" list="#csvfile#" delimiters="#chr(10)##chr(13)#">

        <!---SET VALUES--->           

       <!---TRIM VALUES--->

       <!---SET STRING LENGTH FOR EACH--->

       <!---SET TOTAL STRING--->



       <!---IF FILE FOR BANK EXISTS--->
        <cfif FileExists(ExpandPath("#listgetAt('#index#',5)#.txt"))>

            <!---READ EXISTING FILE HEADER--->
            <cffile action="read" file="C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/kelly2/#bankname#.txt" variable="bankheader">
            <!---SPLIT UP THE HEADER TO ADD NEW VALUES ONTO IT--->
            <cfset numericvalue = listfirst(bankheader,chr(13))>
            <cfset numericvalue = #Right(numericvalue, 13)#>

            <cfset RecordCountvalue = #Left(numericvalue, 3)#>
            <cfset RecordCountvalue = #RecordCountvalue# + 1>
            <cfset RecordCountvalue = #NumberFormat(RecordCountvalue,"000")#>
            <cfset RecordCountvalue = #Left(RecordCountvalue, 3)#>
            <cfset RecordCountvalue = #RJustify(RecordCountvalue, 3)#>

            <cfset TotalRecordvalue = #Right(numericvalue, 10)#>
            <cfset TotalRecordvalue = (#TotalRecordvalue# + #amount#) * 100000>
            <cfset TotalRecordvalue = #NumberFormat(TotalRecordvalue,"0000000000")#>
            <cfset TotalRecordvalue = #Left(TotalRecordvalue, 10)#>
            <cfset TotalRecordvalue = #RJustify(TotalRecordvalue, 10)#>

            <!---SET HEADER FOR FILE--->
            <cfset fileheader_bank = "#UCase(bankname)#">
            <cfset fileheader_bank = "#Left(fileheader_bank, 15)#">
            <cfset fileheader_bank = "#LJustify(fileheader_bank, 16)#">
            <cfset newfile_header = "#fileheader_bank##RecordCountvalue##TotalRecordvalue#">

            <!---APPEND FILE AND ADD UPDATED HEADER--->
            <cfset bankheader = listSetAt(bankheader,1,"#newfile_header#","#chr(13)#")>
            <cffile action="write" file="#getDirectoryFromPath(getTemplatePath())#/#listgetAt('#index#',5)#.txt" output="#bankheader#">

            <!---APPEND FILE AND ADD NEW ENTRY--->
            <cffile action = "append"  
            file = "C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/kelly2/#listgetAt('#index#',5)#.txt"  
            output = "#total_string#">

        </cfif>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

I am pretty sure the problem is in one of these cffile tags.

```
<!---APPEND FILE AND ADD UPDATED HEADER--->
                <cfset bankheader = listSetAt(bankheader,1,"#newfile_header#","#chr(13)#")>
                <cffile action="write" file="#getDirectoryFromPath(getTemplatePath())#/#listgetAt('#index#',5)#.txt" output="#bankheader#">

                <!---APPEND FILE AND ADD NEW ENTRY--->
                <cffile action = "append"  
                file = "C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/kelly2/#listgetAt('#index#',5)#.txt"  
                output = "#total_string#">
```

I have removed a lot of the unnecessary but if you need any of it please let me know.

Comment: `Trim()` might help out

Comment: If you read the [documentation on cffile attributes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7372.html) it explains why: `addNewLine` - yes: appends newline character to text written to file. **Default: yes**

Comment: Hi Leigh! I have now added in fixnewline="no" into all of my cffile tags, it doesn't seem to be helping. I still have an empty line after the second line

Comment: That is a different attribute than the one I mentioned.

Comment: As recently as this week I have experienced the situation where carraige returns in my programming code find their way into an output text file.

Comment: Thanks Leigh! Sorry my mind is somewhere else today

Answer (score 1):

If you used CFScript you would not have the issue. Because your using ColdFusion Tags returns and spaces affect document layout. Try minifiying your code to remove any floating returns / spaces. I have run into this issue with creating PDF files in CF